# Hide filenames for product images

Tags: php, filenames

Is there any way that I can hide the image filenames for all products on a website so that, even if someone chooses to view the page source or image properties, they can't?
I need a way to hide the filenames because in some cases they contain information that i dont want to display to the public.

Comment: Why not just rename the files?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a PHP script that takes an opaque image ID, finds the corresponding image, and writes it out to the response stream.

Thus, the image URLs on the client would look like `../Image.php?ID=<something useless>`.

Remember to set the `Content-Type`.

Comment: Mmm yeah, but this is sub-optimal because a PHP process gets started for every request. Then you have to deal with caching, emitting the correct content type.... It's often the only solution but needs a lot of attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use different techniques, e.g. use md5 function to generate a hash for image file name and store the images in any directory, push their path info in database and then get from database..

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the files and giving them some random name would the simplest way to go.

If that's not an option, using a PHP frontend as @SLaks shows is the second-simplest way to go. It's a bit resource consuming, but okay if you don't have a lot of traffic.

If you *do* have a lot of traffic and are a bit advanced with Apache, you could also consider using an [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). It makes Apache to look up URL substitutions from a text file, which is faster than passing the resource through PHP. It will require some fiddling to get it to work, though.