# Download script for hidden image-url

Tags: php, image, url, download, hidden

I've looked all over the place for this one...

([download link hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514171/download-link-hidden))

([Hide filenames for product images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635691/hide-filenames-for-product-images))

([Hiding image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852279/hiding-image-url))

Now, I'd like to download an image but it has no url whatoever... The php page contains some text and 1 image, if you rightclick and copy the imageurl you get someting like:

```
www.example.com/index.php?module=Profile&file=showuserinfo&function=showuserinfo&userid=2090
```

Ok. That doesn't seem like a downloadable image... Indeed with wget, it just gives me a index.php file. So I tried WinHTTrack... There I get a nice copy of all the text. But what's missing in both the page and contentfolder? The freaking image... It's like a ghost image..

Now this will be a stupid thing, and call me dumb, but I've never seen anything like this... Is there a way to download this image?

Answer (score 0):

If an image is visible in a web browser, it is downloadable. Browsers MUST download an image prior to displaying it.

There are all sorts of ways to make it *harder* to save the image to a local file, but none of these will defeat someone who knows anything about HTML. Two of my favorites are to change the extension of the image to a script file (i.e. myimage.php?id=1234 instead of myimage.png) which makes it a little more difficult to identify which element in the source is the image and to wrap the image behind a div that has a transparent background, which makes the right-click -> save image command useless.

Also, wrapping the image inside a script allows you to impose certain conditions before the image is transmitted; maybe the user must be logged in; maybe the request must come from a script that sends a token you generate on page load... there are all sorts of creative things you can do to make it harder.

But making it impossible to download the image is impossible in HTTP.